# Modify the field of a class in various ways. Use decorators?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a structure like this:

```
struct CalibrationInputs {
  float eta;
  float rawcl_Es0;
  float rawcl_Es1;
  float rawcl_Es2;
  float rawcl_Es3;
};
```

This is the input of a big function

```
float calibrate(CalibrationInput inputs)
```

I want to apply the `calibrate` function using biases inputs, so I need a way to modify the field of `CalibrationInputs`. This is an easy task, but I want to do it in a good way. What I am doing now is:

```
class BiasBase
{
public:
    BiasBase(float amount, std::string type) : m_amount(amount), m_type(type) { };
    virtual void bias(CalibrationInputs & calibration_inputs) = 0;
    std::string get_name() const { return m_type + "_" + get_amount_string(); };
    float get_amount() const { return m_amount; };
protected:
    float m_amount;
    std::string m_type;
};

class BiasE2 : public BiasFixed
{
  BiasE2(float amount) : BiasFixed(amount, "E2") { };
  void bias(CalibrationInputs & calibration_inputs) {
    calibration_inputs.rawcl_Es2 *= (1 + m_amount);
  }
};

class BiasE1 ...
class VeryComplexBias ...
class RandomBiasE2 ...
```

I'm using them as:

```
CalibrationInput input;
CalibrationInput input_bias_e1 = input;
...
BiasE1 bias_e1(0.01);
bias_e1.apply_bias(input_bias_e1);
float result = calibrate(input);
float result_bias_e1 = calibrate(input_bias_e1);
...
```

the problem is: what if I want to combine the `Bias` classes, to apply at the same time two or more biases? I don't want to overcomplicate this easy problem, but maybe I can use decorators. The problem is that every decorator class need to inherite from `CalibrationInputs`, so I'm duplicating every time the fiels, no?

What is a good design for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this question a while on friday, but I was not able to find a realy good solution which works in various ways. I suggest using binders (std::mem_fn, boost.Bind boost.Phoenix) to transform your members to function objects. After this step you can create:

- polymorphic function objects (std::function, boost.Function) to pass around these "members" in a uniform way
- use these function objects in templates to combine them and create more complex function objects.

If you need additional runtime configuration of bias types you could think implementing a kind of interpreter using boost.Spirit. 
I hope this helps.